# MySQL bitwise comparison

Tags: mysql, comparison, bit-manipulation

I have mysql with a user table with answers from a poll saved as a bitwise. How do I find the user with most or least common answers with the reference bitwise?

```
+------+---------+--+
| User | Answers |  |
+------+---------+--+
| A    |       1 |  |
| B    |       5 |  |
| C    |      10 |  |
+------+---------+--+
```

Comment: Can you provide the example output you are looking for given this data as well?

Comment: I would not do this in mysql because you need to compare every user with every other user to get the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming by 'reference bitwise' you mean that you have another value that is a bitmask that you are trying to match against the `Answers` column, something like this should do it for you.  In this case, I'm using '4' as the reference bitmask and `myTable` as the name of your table..

```
SELECT User, BIT_COUNT(Answers & 4) AS MatchedBits FROM myTable ORDER BY MatchedBits DESC
```

This returns:

```
+------+-------------+
| User | MatchedBits |
+------+-------------+
| B    |           1 |
| A    |           0 |
| C    |           0 |
+------+-------------+
```

You can also add a `LIMIT 1` clause to get just the top result, but of course that won't tell you if there is more than one top result with the same number of bits matched.